# Displaying Animation Effect on slider's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jQuery UI slider. Is there any way to display current animated slider value if I click on any slider-range?

Currently, the slider value doesn't get animated while the slider is 'sliding', provided slider's `animate: true;`

---

**For example:**

- Slider starting value: 0.
- I clicked on Slider range: 20.
- Final Slider value: 20.

---

It just changed from 0 to 20 instead of 0->1->2->3->4->5->6 ... ->19->20. (Animation effect on changed value). Which is similar to this web's slider: [Slider Example](http://westciv.com/tools/gradients/) . Anyone can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your wanting to have the **Slider Button** move to and from different parts of the **Slider Bar** with **Numeric Updates** seen on the webpage.

This [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkQ8y/) does that, as well as animates the Button automatically when a preset value is clicked on.

**EDIT:** Per your recent requirements via clarified example, here's a better method that achieves the same thing *using already **known** values*... no need to calculate using expensive `JavaScript Math.ceil()`.

[New jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkQ8y/8/)

The bonus is that the known **percentage** is provided as a **floating point value** which can make a difference on how it's to be used or if there are **markers/hotspots** on top/bottom of the Slider Bar.

Comment: Is this your fiddle? That looks pretty well documented, thanks bro :) But that wasn't what I want, I have figured out the solution of mine already, and made some update on your fiddle. Click on the slider range bar, Check it out :)

Comment: Yes, I made it for a CSS3 Rotate function and always give more comments than what's typically needed to help new people to jQuery. Now that I know what you want, check out my latest answer.

Comment: That is so true, well documented program always keeps new people understand :) Checked, it was nice! =) I guessed I've got to give you a credit for your hard work :)

Answer (score 1):

Check [My Solution on animated slider value](http://jsfiddle.net/wkQ8y/6/). Credited @arttronics as I updated my solution on top of his [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkQ8y/). :)

Try to click on the slider bar to see the value get animated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to add the animate property to the slider.  For example:

```
  $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        value: 1,
        animate: true,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {              
             $('#amount').val(ui.value);                 
         }

});
```

Here is jquery UI slider example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#multiple-vertical

Comment: The OP and I have posted two jsFiddle's that will show what the value is, in numeric form, as it animates to and from positions on the slider. That's what the OP is looking for. Check out his Answer and my latest jsFiddle and see if you have a better method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the jQuery UI slider, try:

```
$('div#foo')
    .slider({
        animate: true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
           $('div#bar').text(ui.value);         
        }
    });
```

### EDIT

I found this code somewhere on the web (can't remember who to give credit) when I had a need to show the animation effect on increasing and decreasing numbers:

```
var num_holder = $('#foo');
        $({ someValue: 0 }).animate({
            someValue: 100
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            easing:'swing',
            step: function() {
                num_holder.text(Math.ceil(this.someValue))
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cVndp/

This is totally untested but perhaps it will work:

```
$('div#foo')
    .slider({
        animate: true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            $({ someValue: 0 }).animate({
                someValue: ui.value
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                easing:'swing',
                step: function() {
                    $('div#bar').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue))
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

You probably have to change the `someValue` from 0 to whatever the previous place's value was. And also change the direction of the animation depending on which way the slider is being pulled, but it's a starting point.

Comment: Ya, I can get this done, and this was my original code :) But the ui.value doesn't change smoothly instead it just changed to the point you've clicked.

Comment: @Roylee what do you mean by "doesn't change smoothly". Do you want an animation effect on the numbers as they go up and down?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have just updated my question :) Sorry if I didnt mentioned it clearly at beginning :)